# cannot find "NT SERVICE\WdiServiceHost" for Windows 10 GPO configuration

Tags: windows, windows-10, group-policy

Cannot find "NT SERVICE\WdiServiceHost" host account. CIS recommends it to be added to "Profile system performance" policy for Win 10. we are using 1803 Win 10 OS and 2008R2 Servers.

Any Idea ?

Comment: Please don't vote for closing this post, as this is a real problem with a verified solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This string value of this account, `WdiServiceHost`, may be problemematic
on foreign language operating system installations
(as is also the case with some other accounts).
You may bypass this problem by using instead the security identifier of the
problematic accounts.

Some of these security ids are well-known and documented, but
the security id of the `NT SERVICE\WdiServiceHost` account is not documented
(or at least not easily found).

Use this security identifier for the "NT SERVICE\WdiServiceHost" account: `S-1-5-80-3139157870-2983391045-3678747466-658725712-1809340420`.

[source](http://centrel1.rssing.com/browser.php?indx=15346048&item=197)

Comment: Thnx, It worked.

Comment: If my answer has helped with the problem, please accept it (tick the V sign).

Comment: My level is too low to up vote ur solution

Comment: This is your post, so you may *accept* an answer by clicking on the V sign to the left. Upvote is different and done with the up arrow sign.